# Animated moving gradient background flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I want to have this moving background in flutter. I don't know what to name it or say, could anyone help me on how do i create such kind of background moving smoothly with animation.

[Animated background](https://youtube.com/shorts/opu45TO3MGo?feature=share)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. If you have a designed animation file you may be able to just show it directly (.gif images just work) or use a package to support it (for things like Lottie).

If you want to use animated widgets, you probably won't get quite the result shown in that clip, but you can use AnimatedContainer builders to manually construct the gradients. It looks like this post did something similar that might get you started [Animate linear gradient background of container in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76496575/animate-linear-gradient-background-of-container-in-flutter)

There's also a package for animating gradients, which could be a good choice (I haven't used it before): https://pub.dev/packages/animate_gradient

Comment: None of them actaully solves my requirement. I want almost the same thing as in the video. I even don't know what we call it.

Comment: Your best bet to mimic the video is to use external animation software to create it, export the animation file, and set it as the background (bottom layer of a stack, probably?) where you want it.